# Get Instance of self written Zend_Controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, controller

I have an Callback-Method `setStatusCallback()`. I want to override the Action-Method `statusAction()` which is placed on my `User_IndexController-Class`. I know that I can override a Callback-Method to `setStatusCallback()` using

```
setStatusCallback(array(&$obj, 'statusAction'));
```

However, when I write

```
$obj = new User_IndexController();
setStatusCallback(array(&$obj, 'statusAction'));
```

this does not work, because `User_IndexController()` needs `$request`. How can I get an instance of `User_IndexController`? I don't know how to handle this `$request`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you have to create an instance of a controller object yourself, Zend_Application should do it for you.  But if you need to create it yourself, try:

```
$obj = new User_IndexController(new Zend_Controller_Request_Http(),
                                new Zend_Controller_Response_Http());
```

You can simply create an instance of a `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` object and pass it to the `Zend_Controller_Action` constructor with no special requirements.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 100% sure, you are doing it wrong. I can't think of any reason why you should need to have Controller object ready before using it.

It also may be better idea to use request and response already created by ZF. Those located in

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest() // or ->getResponse()
```

Comment: I admit, it is an every uncommon situation. I will explain it to you. But at the beginnig i will ad, that my plan i had is not working, we can say it was kind of stupid. Ok, you know Gearman? I wanted to start the client by Cronjob and give the Status back to an ActionMethod of my Controller. And I was also using the Progressbar, which i had to use an ActionMethod, which I can call over URL. Yeah that's why I needed an instance of my Controller, to overgive the Gearman Status to my ActionMethod which should called by the <iframe> of the ProgressBar. I know now that this is not working.

Comment: But the Answer of drew was right, that's how it works to call an instance of your Controller.
For everyone how wants to show the Status of Gearman and monitor them, like i will, take a look at https://github.com/yugene/Gearman-Monitor

Comment: I agree that it is the right solution to the problem. My point is that the problem should never occur, unless your design if wrong :) And then you should fix your design rather than use this :)